# img with two different properties in css

Tags: html, css

I would like to be able to have for example two img classes with different properties. For example in css I want to have:

```
img {
  padding-left: 15pt;
  float: right;
}
```

and then:

```
img1 {
  padding-left: 15pt;
  float: left;
}
```

where `img1` should be a tag for image so I can use it in html for example as:

```
<img1 src="myimage.png" alt="m"/>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: just define the style `img1` and in HTML code use it as `<img src=".." class="img">` This should work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are using like <s>`<img1 />`</s> is **invalid HTML tag**, inorder to select the elements uniquely, we define `class` or `id` to the elements, even if for some reason you don't want to define a `class` or an `id`, you can define [*Custom Attributes*](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20101019/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) to the element, having a prefix of `data-` but you **cannot define** *Custom HTML Elements*, ..

Defining `class` to each `img` tag.. *(Declaring `id`, make sure they are unique for each, you cannot use the same `id` on multiple elements..)*

```
<img src="" class="img1" />
<img src="" class="img2" />
```

And than we write respective CSS like

```
.img1 {
   /* Selects element having a class of .img1 */
}

.img2 {
   /* Selects element having a class of .img2 */
}
```

---

Supposing you have common properties to be declared for both, group them using a comma, and than redeclare the unique properties for the other `class` like

```
.img1, .img2 {
   padding-left: 15pt;
   /* Other common properties goes here */
}

.img2 {
   /* Unique properties for .img2 */
}
```

If you are not looking to assign a `class` to each `img` tag, than you can use `:nth-of-type` or `:nth-child` pseudo to select each `img`, but make sure you wrap them using a `div` or `section` anything you feel is appropriate...

Suppose we wrap them inside a `div` tag, and we assign a `class` say `.container`

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="" />
    <img src="" />
</div>
```

So here you can select the first `img` as

```
.container img:nth-of-type(1) {
   /* Properties here will apply to first img tag nested inside element having
      class of .container */
}

.container img:nth-of-type(2) {
   /* Properties here will apply to second img tag nested inside element having
      class of .container */
}
```

Note: These are CSS3 pseudo, but these are widely supported but as usual, older IE versions will spoil the game, though polyfills are available, but at the end you have to decide you want to choose what.

Also, specificity matters in each of the selectors I've defined above, if you aren't aware of specificity, than give a quick read [**here**](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)...

Answer (score 2):

You can not define custom tags in html, should use CSS classes for what you want to accomplish.

```
<img class=img1 src="myimage.png" alt="m"/>
<img class=img2 src="myimage2.png" alt="m"/>

.img1 {
  padding-left: 15pt;
  float: left;
}

.img2 {
  padding-left: 15pt;
  float: right;
}
```